fullcalendar invert week days and hours in timeGridWeek
I have a working calendar using Fullcalendar V6. as a timeGridWeek all the events are loaded and displayed correctly but I want to have a custom view where the weekdays should now be displayed as rows and the time should be displayed as columns.
Is there any way to do this natively or by adding a few options?
I am using only plain javascript

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

FullCalendar doesn't provide a standard view for showing weekdays as rows and time as columns. However, you can accomplish this layout by employing FullCalendar's custom view options and resource functionalities, paired with specific CSS styling. Please share your code first so I can provide a better solution.

As of fullCalendar version 6 there is no built-in functionality to do this, no.
You can either attempt to write your own custom view or  you can consider making a feature request.
